# How to unset / destroy session that retrieves data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session

My problem is I am having a cart_array which store the product added into my cart. when I press submit and process through the first block of php, if there's sufficient data, it should go to the  unset($_SESSION['cart_array']); part and destroy the cart_array, however, it does not do so, the item added still show up in my cart.php. I tried session_destroy also no luck. Thing to note is that it does echo out $success which means the code should pass through that part but why it didn't unset my cart_array?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['cartOutput']) {


$customer_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_name']);
$tel_num = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['tel_num']);
$customer_address = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_address']);
$customer_messages = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_messages']);
$error_status = false;

if (empty($customer_name)){
$error_customer_name ='<h4>Please Fill Your Name</h4>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($tel_num)){
$error_tel_num='<h4>Please Fill Your Contact Number</h4>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($customer_address)){
$error_customer_address='<h4>Please Fill Your Address</h4>';
$error_status = true;
}

if(!$error_status) {
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php";
$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (customer_name,tel_num,customer_address,product_name, price, quantity, date_added,customer_messages) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_POST["item_name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $customer_name,$tel_num,$customer_address, $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i],$customer_messages);
$stmt->execute();
}
 ; 

$to_address="someone@gmail.com";
$subject="Online Store Order Submission";

$cartTotal=$_POST['cartTotal'];

$message="Input from online order form.\n\n";
$message .="Name: ".$customer_name."\n";
$message .="Tel: ".$tel_num."\n";
$message .="Address: ".$customer_address."\n";
$message .="Messages: ".$customer_messages."\n";
$message .="Total:".$cartTotal."\n";

mail($to_address, $subject, $message);

$success= 'ORDER SUMITTED SUCCESSFULLY! Thank you and WELCOME to shop again!';

unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);

}
}
?>
```

another thing to note is when I make the form action posted to another file let's say order.php and put the above code in it, it UNSET the session, of cause i change the POST to ISSET and put exit() after the unset thou, when i try to put exit() in my cart.php it just go blank if it submitted succesffully.

any help would be appreciated

The below are all the PHP BLOCK above HTML tag for the reference.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['cartOutput']) {


$customer_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_name']);
$tel_num = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['tel_num']);
$customer_address = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_address']);
$customer_messages = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['customer_messages']);
$error_status = false;

if (empty($customer_name)){
$error_customer_name ='<h4>Please Fill Your Name</h4>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($tel_num)){
$error_tel_num='<h4>Please Fill Your Contact Number</h4>';
$error_status = true;
} 
if (empty($customer_address)){
$error_customer_address='<h4>Please Fill Your Address</h4>';
$error_status = true;
}

if(!$error_status) {
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php";
$sql= 'INSERT INTO orders (customer_name,tel_num,customer_address,product_name, price, quantity, date_added,customer_messages) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)';      

$stmt = $myConnection->prepare($sql); 
$countArray = count($_POST["item_name"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $customer_name,$tel_num,$customer_address, $_POST['item_name'][$i], $_POST['amount'][$i], $_POST['quantity'][$i],$customer_messages);
$stmt->execute();
}
 ; 

$to_address="someone@gmail.com";
$subject="Online Store Order Submission";

$cartTotal=$_POST['cartTotal'];

$message="Input from online order form.\n\n";
$message .="Name: ".$customer_name."\n";
$message .="Tel: ".$tel_num."\n";
$message .="Address: ".$customer_address."\n";
$message .="Messages: ".$customer_messages."\n";
$message .="Total:".$cartTotal."\n";

mail($to_address, $subject, $message);

$success= 'ORDER SUMITTED SUCCESSFULLY! Thank you and WELCOME to shop again!';

unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);

}
}
?>

<?php
    session_start();
    /* Created by Adam Khoury @ www.developphp.com */
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php";


    // Query the module data for display ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT modulebody FROM modules WHERE showing='1' AND name='footer' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $footer = $row["modulebody"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Query the module data for display ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT modulebody FROM modules WHERE showing='1' AND name='custom1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $custom1 = $row["modulebody"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Build Main Navigation menu and gather page data here -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error());

    $menuDisplay = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $pid = $row["id"];
        $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
        $menuDisplay .= '<a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' .
                $linklabel . '</a><br />';
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //mysqli_close($myConnection); 
    // This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
    // Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
    // http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
    // Script Error Reporting
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
        $pid = $_POST['pid'];
        $wasFound = false;
        $i = 0;
        // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
        if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
            // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
            $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
        } else {
            // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
                $i++;
                while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                    if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                        // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                        array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                        $wasFound = true;
                    } // close if condition
                } // close while loop
            } // close foreach loop
            if ($wasFound == false) {
                array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
            }
        }
        header("location: cart.php");
        exit();
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 2 (if user chooses to empty their shopping cart)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] === 'emptycart') {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 3 (if user chooses to adjust item quantity)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
        // execute some code
        $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
        if ($quantity >= 100) {
            $quantity = 99;
        }
        if ($quantity < 1) {
            $quantity = 1;
        }
        if (empty($quantity)) {
            $quantity = 1;
        }
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                    // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                } // close if condition
            } // close while loop
        } // close foreach loop
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 4 (if user wants to remove an item from cart)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && $_POST['index_to_remove'] !== '') {
        // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
        $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
        if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"][$key_to_remove]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //       Section 5  (render the cart for the user to view on the page)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $cartOutput = "";
    $cartTotal = "";
    $pp_checkout_btn = '';
    $product_id_array = '';

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
        $cartOutput = "<h3 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h3>";
    } else {
        // Start PayPal Checkout Button

        $pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action=" " method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartOutput" value = "$cartOutput">';

        // Start the For Each loop
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";
            $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $product_name = $row["product_name"];
                $price = $row["price"];
                $details = $row["details"];
            }
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
            $pricetotal = money_format("%10.2n", $pricetotal);
    // Dynamic Checkout Btn Assembly

            $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="' . $product_name . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="' . $price . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">  ';
            // Create the product array variable
            $product_id_array .= "$item_id-" . $each_item['quantity'] . ",";
            // Dynamic table row assembly
            $cartOutput .= "<tr>";
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center><a href="product.php?id=' . $item_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a><br /><img src="inventory_images/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="40" height="52" border="0" /></center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center>RM' . $price . '</center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center><form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
            <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
            <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
            </form></center></td>';
            //$cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $each_item['quantity'] . '</center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center>' . $pricetotal . '</center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '<td><center><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></center></td>';
            $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "ms_MY");
        $cartTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
        $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : " . $cartTotal . " MYR</div>";
        // Finish the Paypal Checkout Btn
         $pp_checkout_btn .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $product_id_array . '">
<div id="table">
    Name: <input type="text" name="customer_name">
    <br/>
    Tel: <input type="text" name="tel_num">
    <br/>
    Address: <input type="text" name="customer_address">
    <br/>
    Messages: <textarea name="customer_messages">

</textarea>

    <input type="hidden" name="cartTotal" value="' . $cartTotal . '">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
        </form>';


    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the session as in `unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);` you have to have a session to manipulate.

So if you add a `session_start();` at the top of the first piece of code, it will probably unset correctly

As in :-

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_POST['cartOutput']) {

....
```